# Simple question related to an ANN diagram showing all of the matrices' dimensions: inputs, weights and output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've been reading [a few Neural Networks articles](https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-1-artificial-neural-networks-d7834f67a4f6) for the past week and one thing that I am still trying to grasp is the dimensioning of the matrices on an ANN training. I have created a diagram (based on the example given by the same article) to try to figure it out.  I have inserted the weights related to the neurons that are painted on the diagram.

I am hoping that someone can validate my reasoning, as it is one of my pain points right now.

I would really appreciate any help.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the bias term, as it is pointed out in your reference article, yes, you seem to be doing right. Normally, each node you draw should contain another input, with its input side being equal to $1$. That way, your equations would look like $x.w+b$.